# Itertools.product to customize the amount of combos for each input?

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools, data-science

I'm using itertools.product to come up with a combination of groups.I'm bad at explaining without examples, so here's code as is.

```
group1=[1,2,3];group2=[4,5,6];group3=[7,8,9]
list(itertools.product(group1,group2,group3))
```

This gives me all combinations of 1 from each group. But how would I go about getting combinations of 2 numbers from group 1, 2 numbers from group 2, and 1 number from group 3?

So for example, I'd like the combination (1,2,5,6,9) to be in the list. Is it possible to customize this? itertools.product doesn't seem to be as flexible as I need it to be, and I've been unsuccessful in learning cartesian products enough to understand how to tweak the .product function.

EDIT: I made the groups small to keep it simple, but each group will have hundreds of unique values.

Comment: You need product of `[1, 2]`, `[5, 6]` and `[9]` or the combinations of `[1, 2, 5, 6, 9]`

Comment: If group1, group2, and group3 all have 200 elements, you're looking at something like 79202000000 different possibilities, which is way too many to iterate over even though we're not materializing them.  Are you sure you're asking the question you actually need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the cartesian product of the r-combinations of each group:

```
from itertools import product, chain, combinations, permutations

groups = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
counts = (2, 2, 1)

selections = [combinations(g, c) for g, c in zip(groups, counts)]

for n_tuple in product(*selections):
    print(tuple(chain.from_iterable(n_tuple)))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 8)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 9)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 8)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 5, 6, 8)
(1, 2, 5, 6, 9)
(1, 3, 4, 5, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 5, 8)
(1, 3, 4, 5, 9)
(1, 3, 4, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 6, 8)
(1, 3, 4, 6, 9)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 8)
(1, 3, 5, 6, 9)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 8)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 9)
(2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 4, 6, 8)
(2, 3, 4, 6, 9)
(2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
(2, 3, 5, 6, 8)
(2, 3, 5, 6, 9)
```

You can change `combinations` to `permutations` if order matters when selecting from each group (for example, if `(3, 2, 5, 6, 9)` is different from `(2, 3, 5, 6, 9)`).

You should note that this produces `choose(|g1|, c1) * choose(|g2|, c2) * ... * choose(|gN|, cN)` elements from `N` groups, where `choose(n, k)` is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). This is incalculably large if your group sizes are in the hundreds as you say--or if the number of groups is large, as well.